# Mysqli result set never false

Tags: php, mysqli

I have run into a problem in my code that I cannot appear to solve tonight.  I'm hoping that another set of eyes will see what I'm missing.

Here is the class.

```
class DB {
    var $DBUser = 'user';
    var $DBPass = 'password';
    var $DBServer = 'localhost';
    var $DBName = 'database';
    var $con;
    var $new_id = 0;

function __construct() {
    $testcon = new mysqli($this->DBServer, $this->DBUser, $this->DBPass, $this->DBName);
        if (!$testcon) {
            die('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
            $this->con = $testcon;
        }
 }

function select($sql) {
        $rs=$this->con->query($sql);
        if($rs === false) {
            printf("Query is empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            return $rs;
        }
  }
 }
```

Whenever I send a query to my "select" function I expect it to return either the result set or a false, so that I can deal with it accordingly.  But no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to go into the $rs === false if statement above.  It even lets me take that empty result set and do a fetch_assoc on it, but there is no resulting array.

Please tell me I'm just stupid and missed something because this is making me pull my hair out.

Comment: Everything works as expected. Just get rid of that useless if($rs === false) condition.

Comment: Though it makes whole class quite useless and crippled, compared to original mysqli.

Comment: I want to make it object oriented but I've always done it the procedural way.   Can I scrap the class and still use object oriented approach like  $db= new mysqli(stuff) and do it that way?   Is there a benefit to creating my own class?

Comment: Yes there is a benefit, but only if you have an idea why you need a class. So for a while stick to vanilla mysqli